# How to upload file with content to Firebase Storage Bucket from Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have been following the documentation on how to upload files [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample)

So I have the following:

```js
await admin.storage().bucket().file("test.txt").save("Some text");
```

After this I can see my file successfully uploaded to my bucket:

[image]

but whenever I try to open it, it gives me an undefined URL:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project/storage/my-project.appspot.com/undefined
```

Which causes a redirect and I can't access the file from the browser or programatically from my cloud function
I have also tried to make sure the file is public by running this right after the creation of the file:

```js
await admin.storage().bucket().file("test.txt").makePublic();
```

Maybe I'm missing something silly here but I can't spot it

Thanks for reading me :)

## UPDATE:

There is no problem with the programatic access, also the file can be accessed from GCP Console but the problem opening the file from Firebase console and getting that undefined URL persists

Comment: Are you trying to open the file from Firebase console? Can you try to open the file from Google Cloud console and see if it works? Also, you said you are not able to access the file programmatically, can you mention what error are you getting while accessing the file programmatically?

Comment: Can you go to this link : https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-project.appspot.com/test.txt,  (Change `my-project` to your project id) and see if you are able to access the file?

Comment: Seems like the programatic problem was a logic error from my end, it's fixed as I wasn't parsing the file correctly.

But the issue opening the file from the firebase console still persists as described.

If I try the URL as you mentioned or from GCP it does work, so it seems to be a bug within the firebase console.

I have raised the question on their github repo
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1818